CPQ: Refresh Quote Prices as triggering action
When clicking "Refresh Prices" on a Quote, and ultimately refreshing the prices, is this action reflected in any field on the Quote (or other object)? Or is this action timestamped or "registrered"?
My goal is to have a conditional button show up when a Quote´s prices have been refreshed (by CPQ button).
Other suggestions are highly appreciated!
Thank you!
